# How to compare CGError in Swift

Tags: swift, comparison, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, core-foundation

The code below gives a compiler error on the `if` line: **"Cannot invoke '!=' with an argument list of type '(CGError, _CGError)'"**

```
var fadeToken: CGDisplayFadeReservationToken = 0
let fadeReservationError = CGAcquireDisplayFadeReservation(0.5, &fadeToken)
if fadeReservationError != kCGErrorSuccess {
    println("Failed to fade screen")
}
```

I've tried casting `kCGErrorSuccess as CGError`, and converting both operands to `Int`, but both give other errors. It seems like the `Int32` type (of which `CGError` is a `typealias`), can't be compared: can that be right?

I'm using the public release of Xcode 6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out by looking at the Swift definition of `kCGErrorSuccess`:

```
struct _CGError {
    init(_ value: UInt32)
    var value: UInt32
}
var kCGErrorSuccess: _CGError { get }
...
typealias CGError = Int32
```

And there it is: `CGError` is defined as `Int32`, whereas its potential values are defined as `UInt32`. Taking the `.value` of the constant and converting both operands to `Int` like so, cleared up the compiler error:

```
if Int(fadeReservationError) != Int(kCGErrorSuccess.value) {
```

Comment: Awesome job DOV! By chance do you know where all the `CGError`'s are listed? For instance I am trying to figure out what value of `1000` and `268435459` means

Comment: @Noitidart I jumped to the definition of `CGError` to find the one I posted. If the rest aren't there, I'm not sure where to look

Comment: Thanks Dov for quick reply, I'm actually a beginner at this stuff, what does jumped to definition mean? I actually do this stuff via ctypes, so I don't have a xcode or C/C++ environment.

Comment: @Noitidart Oh, what I'm talking about is a command in Xcode. Do you have a Mac? Even if you're not using Xcode to develop in, you could still use it for browsing headers (it's free on the Mac App Store). When in Xcode, you can use the Navigate -> Jump to Definition menu, or the ^⌘J keyboard shortcut. Otherwise, I don't know of another place where error codes are documented.

Comment: Ah thanks, I have mac but its VM so app store doesnt work :( Ill dig a bit online :)

Comment: @Noitidart Well, you can also download directly from Apple. You need a developer account (but I believe a free one will still work). There are links to all the different versions reachable from here: https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/

Comment: Thanks so much! I will check that and let you know!